# Why am I getting an invalid flag error when trying too compile servlets?

Tags: java, oracle, apache, tomcat, servlets

I'm working on a school project for a databases course and when I try to compile

```
javac -d ../apache-tomcat-6.0.18/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes -
classpath ../apache-tomcat-6.0.18/lib/servlet-api.jar:ojdbc6.jar
*.java
```

I'm getting an invalid flag error? Any idea how to solve this? I have tried removing the spaces and using quotes (as someone suggested) but this did not work.

This is the error.

```
$ javac -d ../apache-tomcat-6.0.18/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes-classpath ../apache-tomcat-6.0.18/lib/servlet-api.jar:ojdbc6.jar *.java
javac: invalid flag: ../apache-tomcat-6.0.18/lib/servlet-api.jar:ojdbc6.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have written `"- classpath"` ... with a space after the `"-"`.

---

Note: the suggestion to quote the paths is not helpful.  It *would* help if there were characters in the pathname that required quoting (e.g. spaces or wildcards that you wanted to be treated literally) but that is not the case here.  Specifically, "-" characters have no special meaning to the shell in this example.

(Randomly quoting things is an example of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).  Avoid it.  If you want to understand how quoting works, and when it is necessary, read "man sh" or a good shell book or tutorial ... or the POSIX shell specification.  Yes folks, there is a >>specification<<.)